# ¿Cómo eliminar HTML dentro de una etiqueta?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una base de datos migrada la cuál no es mía y el anterior usuario guardaba los datos con etiquetas HTML, ahora al obtenerlas me muestra las etiquetas en cuestión, hay alguna forma de eliminarlas usando jQuery?

Esto es el texto que se muestra en la página web, es decir no coge la etiqueta dado que en la BBDD entiendo que está guardado como `String`

```
> <a href='/img/imagen.jpg' target='_blank'>Información</a>
```

He intentado hacer un

```
var valor = $('.fila a').text();

var valor = $('.fila a').val();

var valor = $('.fila a').html();
```

Ninguna de las 3 anteriores me ha parecido funcionar, también he intentado

```
valor.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Y esta última me elimina incluso las etiquetas de la página, alguna posible solución?

Mi página actualmente se ve así

```
<td class="field">
<a href='/img/imagen.jpg' target='_blank'>Información</a> <!-- este link se muestra como texto y deseo eliminar su etiqueta -->
</td>
<td class="field">
<a href='/img/ayuda.jpg' target='_blank'>Ayuda</a> <!-- este link se muestra como texto y deseo eliminar su etiqueta -->
</td>
```

Comment: ¿quieres decir que lo que necesitas en este caso es ese texto `Información` y deshacerte del resto?

Comment: @dteterevkov exactamente, ahora mismo me muestra todo el texto

Comment: También, lo que se guarda en la BBDD, ¿empieza por `>` o se te coló?

Comment: @dteterevkov se me coló al intentar hacer una cita, gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que recuperas de la BBDD como bien dices es un string. Tienes que convertirlo en HTML primero y a continuación, puedes extraer su texto, así:

```js
let bbdd_extract = "<a href='/img/imagen.jpg' target='_blank'>Información</a>";
console.log($(bbdd_extract).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**: como dices en los comentarios, recibes eso directamente desde el backend y has de hacer el cambio en cliente. Puedes modificarlo una vez la página esté cargada:

```js
$(function() {
  $('td.field').each(function(i) {
    let tag_as_string = $(this).text();
    let tag_text = $(tag_as_string).html();
    $(this).text(tag_text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="field">
<a href='/img/imagen.jpg' target='_blank'>Información</a> <!-- este link se muestra como texto y deseo eliminar su etiqueta -->
</td>
<td class="field">
<a href='/img/ayuda.jpg' target='_blank'>Ayuda</a> <!-- este link se muestra como texto y deseo eliminar su etiqueta -->
</td>
```

Comment: Con `$(bbdd_extract).html()` también debería valer.

Comment: Podría hacerlo más general? Es decir sustituir el string del extract a algun otro, dado que no es el unico campo que sufre el problema

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez ¿a qué te refieres?¿podrías poner un ejemplo? Gracias

Comment: Gracias @Kiko_L por el aporte. Tienes toda la razón.

Comment: @dteterevkov me refiero a que por ejemplo, hay más strings así. Todos los de la base de datos para ser exactos. Pero entiendo que eso solo eliminaria el de información. Actualizo mi pregunta con más ejemplos de mi código.

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez en la base de datos ¿qué hay exactamente? ¿la etiqueta del link o toda la celda? Si es toda la celda deberás aplicar el código de esta respuesta incluyendo la etiqueta de la celda

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes los strings de la BBDD? ¿Haces una llamada ajax desde JS o los obtienes directamente en tu backend?

Comment: Cómo comenta @Kiko_L, ¿recibes esos datos por ajax? Porque antes de mostrarlos, deberías interceptarlos y modificarlos. Si te llegan desde el backend, igual puedes atacar ahí en vez de delegar la tarea en cliente.

Comment: @Raider llegan desde el backend, el cual es un framework de php que lo uso en su core. No lo puedo modificar por posibles bugs y porque tiene su forma de generarlo. Por eso quería hacerlo del lado del cliente donde si puedo recuperar los datos. En la BBDD está guardado como varchar(255) mysql la etiqueta entera, como se muestra en el ejemplo

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez modifiqué la respuesta original para añadir una manera de hacerlo para los distintos campos. Comprueba que sea esto lo que buscas.

Comment: @dteterevkov funciona correctamente con la página que estoy trabajando! Solo que he añadido una pequeña modificación, una vez recojo los datos con tu respuesta hago un replace con la siguiente expresión `replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Para borrar HTML dentro de una etiqueta puedes hacerlo con `empty()`

Aquí te dejo la documentación: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

```
$("#div1").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te está pintando todo el texto con la etiqueta html tu js no funcionará ya que no lo está reconociendo como un eleménto de la página si no como un string.

Para eliminar el texto de la etiqueta puedes probar lo siguiente

```
var str = "<a href='/img/imagen.jpg' target='_blank'>Información</a>";
var mySubString = str.substring(
    str.indexOf(">") + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf("<")
);
console.log(mySubString);
```

En `mySubString` tienes el texto que hay dentro de la etiqueta.